# Find $f$ such that $f(f(x))=\log (x)$

Tags: complex-integration, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition, lambert-w, power-towers

Which is the solution for the following expression $$f(f(x))=\log (x)?$$
In other words, which function composed with itself matches with logarithm? With $x\in (0,\infty )$.

---

The breakdown of logarithm function can open a door in problems like $x^x=2$.

---

I'm a software engineer with passion for math problems. I'm trying to develop a math framework to abstract logarithm as tool to work with power tower. Actually I'm alone and indipendent.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but the downvote might be due to not having shown your attempt or your thoughts about the question. Some people might think it’s a homework question. I do think it’s an interesting question and I’m curious to learn how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. For example, use MathJax to type the math in your questions, and more importantly, show your own work and thoughts on the problem.

Comment: not an homework! This expr has the seed to solve an awesome problem related to tower power. I'm working on it, I'm looking for fresh ideas

Comment: You shout "not an homework! " Don't do that. Instead try to improve your question.

Comment: I'm happy to push stuff inside question, I'm out of my common desk.

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffx-gx) for solving $f(f(x))=g(x)$

Comment: You should add conditions you want the function to meet. E.g. that it is $C^\infty$ and monotone. Even with that, it is probable that there is an (uncountable) infinity of functions that verify the equation, and that they can be built by interval.

Comment: Helmuth Kneser constructed  a half iterate for $e^x$   and yours is just the inverse function of that. Reele analytische Losungen der  Gleichung $\varphi(\varphi(x)) = e^x,$  year 1950........   https://eudml.org/doc/150158

Comment: Secifically for $x^x=2$, take $\ln$ at both sides: $x\ln x = \ln 2$ and then notice that [Lambert-$W$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) satisfies $W(x\ln x)=\ln x$ and hence $W(x\ln x)=\ln x = W(\ln2)$ which gives $x$ as
$$x = e^{W(\ln 2)}=\dfrac{\ln 2}{W(\ln 2)}$$

Answer (score 4):

Here's an animation with a family of functions $f$ depending on a parameter satisfying the equation (in orange), $\log$ (in blue), $f\circ f$ (in dotted red).

[image]

Comment: did you see the ghost curve! It appear as a logarithm but of another universe. It can drive the concept of rational tetration power tower for rational number as order insted of natural only

Comment: @FrancescoBianco Did you read the Wikipedia page on tetration? The concept of tetration is known to extend to complex bases and complex order.

Comment: At this time there is no commonly accepted solution to the general problem of extending tetration to the real or complex values of n. There have, however, been multiple approaches towards the issue...

Answer (score 2):

We cannot expect that the [half iterate (functional square root)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) is an elementary function or a closed-form function in each case.

You could develop the Taylor series of $f(f(x))$ and calculate its coefficients from the Taylor series of $\ln(x)$ then:

http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ - Continuous functional iteration

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/kth-derivative-of-the-nth-iterate.42909/

https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/kth-derivative-of-the-composition-of-n-functions-pdf.1531/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-exponential_function

Alternatively, you could use $f(x)=f^{-1}(\ln(x))$ together with [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).
$\ $

For inverting power towers ([tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)), we have hyper-Lambert W. see [Solve for $x$ in $^nx = i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485218/solve-for-x-in-nx-i/4485320#4485320)